# How can i print multiline elements on one single row in the terminal?

Tags: ruby, terminal

I'm trying to print a chess grid to the terminal, with each element being output next to each other on the same line, as on a row. However I'd like each element in the row to be two lines deep, whilst maintaining the next element being printed on the same line that the first element started on.

This code with single line elements works ok:

```
  def display_board_utf
    grid.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
      puts "\n\n"
      print ((row_index - 8).abs).to_s + ' '
      row.each_with_index do |piece, column_index|
        if piece.nil?
          if colour_grid[row_index][column_index] == :black
            print("\033[40m| nil |\033[m")
          else
            print("\033[47m| nil |\033[m")
          end
        else
          if colour_grid[row_index][column_index] == :black
            print("\033[40m|#{piece.uni_char + piece.class.to_s.chr.downcase + piece.colour.to_s.chr + colour_emoji(piece.colour)}|\033[m")
          else
            print("\033[47m|#{piece.uni_char + piece.class.to_s.chr.downcase + piece.colour.to_s.chr + colour_emoji(piece.colour)}|\033[m")
          end
        end
      end
      print ' ' + ((row_index - 8).abs).to_s
    end
    puts "\n\n"
  end
```

Image of output of the above:

[image]

Printing a second line for each element of course adds a newline character which means the next printed element will never output at the starting line level of the previous element, resulting in mess like this:

[image]

I've tried playing around with `puts`/`print`/`p` and printing to `$stdout` without achieving what I need, and there isn't a 'line up' command, as far as I can see. Any ideas on how I can create this multi line element single row type output that I'm trying to achieve (without using another library)?

Comment: You need to iterate over your pieces twice

Comment: , that's exactly what I need to do. Thank you for pointing out what should have been obvious to me. And I suppose the point is that there is no way to print over two lines and return up to print a line above again, output in command line is only in one direction, therefore you can't go back and output above something already printed.

Answer (score 1):

"And I suppose the point is that there is no way to print over two lines and return up to print a line above again, output in command line is only in one direction, therefore you can't go back and output above something already printed." The Standard library ships with IO::console. Useless demo:

```
require 'io/console'

c = IO::console
c.clear_screen
sleep 1
c.cursor=[10,10]
print "I am here"
sleep 1
c.cursor_up(3)
sleep 1
c.cursor_left(3)
sleep(1)
print "now I'm here!"
sleep 1
c.clear_screen
```

I do not know if this works in Windows.

Comment: Nice suggestion @steenslag, thanks. I've installed the gem locally and was trying to play with in pry/irb but running `require 'io/console'` returns a `false`. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? 0.6.0 successfully installed according to the console output.

Comment: If you installed a gem it should probably be `io-console` (with a dash). The code in my answer did not require installing any gems - ruby ships with it, but may be not on Windows. Search for win32console gem in that case.

Comment: `require 'io/console'` returned false when i tried it without having installed anything, so I went and installed the `io-console` gem, successfully so according the install's console output. Yet the require still results in false when run in either pry or irb . I'm on Ruby 3.1.2. Any ideas what might be going on? (Thanks)

Comment: `require io-console` maybe?

Comment: nope, unfortunately not. It seems to see that 'io-console' is there because it outputs; `Did you mean?  io/console`, then i try `require 'io/console'`, and it gives
`=> false`. Hmmm.